# RedirectMatch htaccess redirect folder to folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

how can I redirect folder to folder for example:

`www.domain.com/folder/w-search to www.domain.com/stackoverflow/w-search`

I try:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/(.*) /stackoverflow/$1`

but it direct me to:

`http://www.domain.com/stackoverflow/w-search?/folder/w-search`

How I can repair it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /stackoverflow/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. The site is not redirected and url does not change.

Comment: So entering `www.domain.com/folder/something` doesn't redirect you to `www.domain.com/stackoverflow/something`?

Comment: Unfortunately, not redirected to www.domain.com/stackoverflow/something

Comment: Can you give an example of a url you are trying to redirect?